# How to use Geometry Node 'Point Distribute' with Cycles Displacement

Tags: cycles-render-engine, displacement, geometry-nodes

Not sure if this is even possible, but is there a way (using geometry nodes) to scatter points along a surface in a cycles render if said surface has a displacement? (Not only a bump.) As it stands the points are scattering across the pre-displacement surface.

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. The geometry nodes cannot access the geometry that is created by the renderer. But maybe there is a way to work with the bump map that you use for the displacement. A invisible displaced dummy object maybe.

Comment: You could try with displacement modifier